# Convert XML Content to string or html format in powershell

Tags: html, xml, powershell

I'm looking for a way to get xml content in string or in html:

I have an xml like:

```
<xml>
  <Students>
    <Name>Karan</Name>
    <Name>Rohan</Name>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <Name>Roy</Name>
  </Students>
</xml>
```

I wrote following code:

```
[xml]$Xml = Get-Content (student.xml)
$str = ConvertTo-Xml -InputObject $Xml.InnerXml -As Stream
```

But, it gives following string to $str and that too in a single line:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <Objects> <Object Type="System.String">&lt;Class&gt;&lt;Students&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Karan&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Rohan&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Jack&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Name&gt;Roy&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;/Students&g
t;&lt;/Class&gt;</Object> </Objects>
```

But I want the string in following format including the whitespaces:

```
'<xml>
  <Students>
    <Name>Karan</Name>
    <Name>Rohan</Name>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <Name>Roy</Name>
  </Students>
</xml>'
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
$str=gc C:\temp\test.xml |Out-String
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get the XML data in a string for you while preserving the format.

```
[String]$str = Get-Content -Path "student.xml" -Raw
```